# OpenWeather API, How do I pass in response from one response to another call?

Tags: javascript, function, openweathermap

I am trying to call the current conditions API, get the response and have the Latitude and Longitude be the parameter of the second call to the OneCall API. Below, you can see I have attempted to do so by passing coord into the function and then declaring  which part of the object to use in each part of the URL, but it keeps coming back undefined.

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <!--Main Heading-->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <h1 id="main-heading">Weather Dashboard</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    
      
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-3">


        <!--Search Bar-->  

                <h5>Search for a City</h5>

                <!--Search Button-->

                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input id="searchBar" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Recently Searched Cities Aside-->

                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-header">
                      Recently Searched Places
                    </div>
                    <ul id="recentSearch" class="list-group list-group-flush">
                      <li class="list-group-item">Minneapolis, MN</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">Dallas, TX</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">San Francisco, CA</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
            </div>

                  <!--Current Conditons Display-->

            <div class="col">
                <div id="currentConditions" class="card">
                    <h5 class="card-header">Current Conditions</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h3 id="cityName" class="card-title">Minneapolis, MN</h3>
                      <p id="currentTemp" class="card-text">Temp: 54</p>
                      <p id="currentHumidity" class="card-text">Humidity: 43</p>
                      <p id="currentWindSpeed" class="card-text">Wind Speed: 12mph</p>
                      <p id="uvIndex" class="card-text">UV Index: 9.49</p>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                  

                  <!--5 Day Forecast-->

                  <h4>5 Day Forecast:</h4>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div id="dayOne" class="fiveDay col">
                    <h5>Live Date</h5>
                    Weird Symbol Thing
                    <p>Temp: 85.45</p>
                    <p>Humidity: 43%</p>
                </div>

                <div id="dayTwo" class="fiveDay col">
                    <h5>Live Date</h5>
                    Weird Symbol Thing
                    <p>Temp: 85.45</p>
                    <p>Humidity: 43%</p>
                </div>

                <div id="dayThree" class="fiveDay col">
                    <h5>Live Date</h5>
                    Weird Symbol Thing
                    <p>Temp: 85.45</p>
                    <p>Humidity: 43%</p>
                </div>

                <div id="dayFour" class="fiveDay col">
                    <h5>Live Date</h5>
                    Weird Symbol Thing
                    <p>Temp: 85.45</p>
                    <p>Humidity: 43%</p>
                </div>

                <div id="dayFive" class="fiveDay col">
                    <h5>Live Date</h5>
                    Weird Symbol Thing
                    <p>Temp: 85.45</p>
                    <p>Humidity: 43%</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            </div>

    </div>

     
    <script src="assets/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js" integrity="sha256-T/f7Sju1ZfNNfBh7skWn0idlCBcI3RwdLSS4/I7NQKQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```js
function buildQueryURL() {

    var baseURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
    var key = "&units=imperial&appid=6c743e42a0f9ac97fab6ec81e5e3acc9";
    var querySearch = $("#searchBar")
        .val()
        .trim();
    var all = baseURL + querySearch + key;
    return baseURL + querySearch + key;
};

function oneCall() {

    var ocBaseURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=";
    var ocLat = coord[0];
    var ocLon = "&lon=" + coord[1];
    var ocKey = "&units=imperial&appid=6c743e42a0f9ac97fab6ec81e5e3acc9";
    return ocBaseURL + ocLat + ocLon + ocKey;
    console.log(ocBaseURL + ocLat + ocLon + ocKey);


};


$("#searchBtn").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var queryURL = buildQueryURL();
    console.log(queryURL);
    $.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function(response) {
        $("#cityName").text(response.name);
        $("#currentTemp").text("Temp: " + response.main.temp);
        $("#currentHumidity").text("Humidity: " + response.main.humidity);
        $("#currentWindSpeed").text("Wind Speed: " + response.wind.speed);
        $("#uvIndex").text("UV Index: " + response.main.temp);
        var coord = response.coord;
        oneCall(coord);
    }).catch(err => {
        // handle error here
        throw new Error(err)
    });

});
```

Comment: What is undefined? The string "ocBaseURL + ocLat + ocLon + ocKey"?

Comment: Yes, I was attempting to pass in the coord var from the previous function and then use each of its values to define the url of the second call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've got some mistakes in your snippet:

1. `function oneCall() {...` should be `function oneCall(coord) {` (the passed parameter when you call the function is not declared in the function itself)
2. `coord` is an object with `lat` and `lon` properties, not an array like you are using it, so you should have `var ocLat = coord.lat` and `var ocLon = "&lon=" + coord.lon`
3. The console.log you have inside the declaration of `oneCall()` won't work since it's after the `return`.

You could also use the `data` option of ajax() settings to querify your parameters for you by providing it an object, see: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings